# Swift collection that has defined types and copies by reference?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, collections

In converting old projects from Objective-C to Swift, I've mostly been able to use `Dictionary` in place of `NSMutableDictionary`. But in some cases, it's a hassle or uses a lot of extra memory to have the Dictionaries copying by value.

I thought I could simply change some `Dictionary` collections to `NSMutableDictionary` to make them objects that copy by value, but I don't see a way to specify the key and value types. This works in Objective-C:

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSString*> *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

But this gives an error "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSMutableDictionary'" in Swift:

```
let dict: NSMutableDictionary<String, String> = [:]
```

Is there a way to specify the types so I don't have to be constantly casting the values I get out of the dictionary?

Alternatively, is there another kind of collection object that supports key and value types like `Dictionary` but copies by reference like `NSMutableDictionary`?

**UPDATE**

I tried using `NSMapTable` as suggested in the comment below. That's missing some features of `NSDictionary` (e.g., it doesn't conform to `IteratorProtocol`), so I made a subclass to try making a drop-in replacement for `Dictionary`. I then ran into problems making my subclass generic since Swift and Objective-C have different support for that.

Since that would either require a lot of casting (or making a different subclass for each type of data I wanted to store in the dictionary), I then tried just using `NSMutableDictionary` and casting all the values when I read them. Unfortunately, after all that work, I couldn't see any difference in memory usage compared to using `Dictionary`.

So I guess having collections that copy by value isn't really my problem. It shouldn't be since I'm never retaining anything for very long, but I didn't see these memory problems until I migrated from Objective-C. I'll have to do more testing and explore other solutions.

Comment: Not exactly 'copy by reference, but [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable) can hold weak reference. Here's a lil more info from [NSHipster](https://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/)

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C specification:

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSString*>
```

Is not a true implementation of Generics.  It simply gives hints to the compiler that the dictionary will contain strings as the keys and values and the compiler can tell you, at compile time, if you make a simple mistake.

At the end of the day, there is nothing at runtime to enforce those type specifications.  An `NSDictionary` (mutable or not) will have `id` for the keys, and `id` for the values and the runtime format will not change.  That's why you can get away with using `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` to initialize all `NSDictionaries`... the type spec only has meaning at compile time.

In contrast when you use a identical syntax in Swift, say `Dictionary<String, Int>`, you *are* using true generics.  The runtime representation of the dictionary may change depending on what key and value types you use.

In other words, in spite of similarities in their in Syntax, the `<type, type>` construct in Objective-C and in Swift mean VERY different things.

In Swift's Eyes, an `NSDictionary` (mutable or not) is simply a `NSObject`, just like every other `NSObject` so NSDictionary<NSString, NSString> is a nonsensical use of the generic type specification syntax - you're saying you want to use generics with a type that is not a generic type (hence the error).

There is no Swift syntax (that I'm aware of) that lets you specify the type you'd like to stand in for `NSObject` in things like `NSDictionaries` and `NSArrays`. You're going to have to use casting.

Even in Objective-C the type specs mean nothing and it's possible to squeeze something in there that doesn't belong.  Consider:

```
 NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 ((NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary)[[NSNumber numberWithInt: 3]] = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.apple.com"];
```

Here I declare the dict to use Strings, then shove in a number and a URL.  The only way to guard against this would be to check the types, that is to **do typecasting** (or at least type-checking), for each key and value. Most folks code doesn't do that because it would be a pain, but the only way to get *true* safety.

Swift, in contrast, focus on the safety right up front.  It's one of the defining differences between Swift an Objective-C.  So you *have* to go through the pain if you insist on using "unsafe" Objective-C types.